# How would I apply this onbeforeload function to this javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to add this onbeforeload script to the following script, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Could someone show me how to add it correctly?

This is the onbeforeload code -

```
(function($) {
$(window).load(function () {
    // retrieved this line of code from http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            src: 'someimage.jpg'
        },
        type: 'image'

      // You may add options here, they're exactly the same as for $.fn.magnificPopup call
      // Note that some settings that rely on click event (like disableOn or midClick) will not work here
    }, 0);
});
})(jQuery);
```

Here's the script I'm trying to add it to -

```
(function(){

if(!window.addEventListener) {
return;
}

var self = window.StyleFix = {
link: function(link) {
try {
  // Ignore stylesheets with data-noprefix attribute as well as alternate stylesheets
  if(link.rel !== 'stylesheet' || link.hasAttribute('data-noprefix')) {
    return;
  }
 }
 catch(e) {
  return;
 }

 var url = link.href || link.getAttribute('data-href'),
    base = url.replace(/[^\/]+$/, ''),
    base_scheme = (/^[a-z]{3,10}:/.exec(base) || [''])[0],
    base_domain = (/^[a-z]{3,10}:\/\/[^\/]+/.exec(base) || [''])[0],
    base_query = /^([^?]*)\??/.exec(url)[1],
    parent = link.parentNode,
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    process;

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
    process();
  }
  };

process = function() {
    var css = xhr.responseText;

    if(css && link.parentNode && (!xhr.status || xhr.status < 400 || xhr.status > 600)) {
      css = self.fix(css, true, link);

      // Convert relative URLs to absolute, if needed
      if(base) {
        css = css.replace(/url\(\s*?((?:"|')?)(.+?)\1\s*?\)/gi, function($0, quote, url) {
          if(/^([a-z]{3,10}:|#)/i.test(url)) { // Absolute & or hash-relative
            return $0;
          }
          else if(/^\/\//.test(url)) { // Scheme-relative
            // May contain sequences like /../ and /./ but those DO work
            return 'url("' + base_scheme + url + '")';
          }
          else if(/^\//.test(url)) { // Domain-relative
            return 'url("' + base_domain + url + '")';
          }
          else if(/^\?/.test(url)) { // Query-relative
            return 'url("' + base_query + url + '")';
          }
          else {
            // Path-relative
            return 'url("' + base + url + '")';
          }
        });

        // behavior URLs shoudn’t be converted (Issue #19)
        // base should be escaped before added to RegExp (Issue #81)
        var escaped_base = base.replace(/([\\\^\$*+[\]?{}.=!:(|)])/g,"\\$1");
        css = css.replace(RegExp('\\b(behavior:\\s*?url\\(\'?"?)' + escaped_base, 'gi'), '$1');
        }

      var style = document.createElement('style');
      style.textContent = css;
      style.media = link.media;
      style.disabled = link.disabled;
      style.setAttribute('data-href', link.getAttribute('href'));

      parent.insertBefore(style, link);
      parent.removeChild(link);

      style.media = link.media; // Duplicate is intentional. See issue #31
    }
  };

  try {
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send(null);
  } catch (e) {
  // Fallback to XDomainRequest if available
  if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.onerror = xhr.onprogress = function() {};
    xhr.onload = process;
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send(null);
  }
 }

link.setAttribute('data-inprogress', '');
},

styleElement: function(style) {
if (style.hasAttribute('data-noprefix')) {
  return;
}
var disabled = style.disabled;

style.textContent = self.fix(style.textContent, true, style);

style.disabled = disabled;
},

styleAttribute: function(element) {
var css = element.getAttribute('style');

css = self.fix(css, false, element);

element.setAttribute('style', css);
},

process: function() {
// Linked stylesheets
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]:not([data-inprogress])').forEach(StyleFix.link);

// Inline stylesheets
$('style').forEach(StyleFix.styleElement);

// Inline styles
$('[style]').forEach(StyleFix.styleAttribute);
},

register: function(fixer, index) {
(self.fixers = self.fixers || [])
  .splice(index === undefined? self.fixers.length : index, 0, fixer);
},

fix: function(css, raw, element) {
for(var i=0; i<self.fixers.length; i++) {
  css = self.fixers[i](css, raw, element) || css;
}

return css;
},

camelCase: function(str) {
return str.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function($0, $1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); }).replace('-','');
},

deCamelCase: function(str) {
return str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function($0) { return '-' + $0.toLowerCase() });
}
};

/**************************************
* Process styles
**************************************/
(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').forEach(StyleFix.link);
}, 10);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', StyleFix.process, false);
 })();

function $(expr, con) {
return [].slice.call((con || document).querySelectorAll(expr));
}

})();

/**
* PrefixFree
*/
(function(root){

if(!window.StyleFix || !window.getComputedStyle) {
return;
}

// Private helper
function fix(what, before, after, replacement, css) {
what = self[what];

if(what.length) {
var regex = RegExp(before + '(' + what.join('|') + ')' + after, 'gi');

css = css.replace(regex, replacement);
}

return css;
}

var self = window.PrefixFree = {
prefixCSS: function(css, raw, element) {
var prefix = self.prefix;

// Gradient angles hotfix
if(self.functions.indexOf('linear-gradient') > -1) {
  // Gradients are supported with a prefix, convert angles to legacy
  css = css.replace(/(\s|:|,)(repeating-)?linear-gradient\(\s*(-?\d*\.?\d*)deg/ig,     function ($0, delim, repeating, deg) {
    return delim + (repeating || '') + 'linear-gradient(' + (90-deg) + 'deg';
  });
 }

css = fix('functions', '(\\s|:|,)', '\\s*\\(', '$1' + prefix + '$2(', css);
css = fix('keywords', '(\\s|:)', '(\\s|;|\\}|$)', '$1' + prefix + '$2$3', css);
css = fix('properties', '(^|\\{|\\s|;)', '\\s*:', '$1' + prefix + '$2:', css);

// Prefix properties *inside* values (issue #8)
if (self.properties.length) {
  var regex = RegExp('\\b(' + self.properties.join('|') + ')(?!:)', 'gi');

  css = fix('valueProperties', '\\b', ':(.+?);', function($0) {
    return $0.replace(regex, prefix + "$1")
  }, css);
 }

 if(raw) {
  css = fix('selectors', '', '\\b', self.prefixSelector, css);
  css = fix('atrules', '@', '\\b', '@' + prefix + '$1', css);
 }

// Fix double prefixing
css = css.replace(RegExp('-' + prefix, 'g'), '-');

// Prefix wildcard
css = css.replace(/-\*-(?=[a-z]+)/gi, self.prefix);

return css;
},

property: function(property) {
return (self.properties.indexOf(property)? self.prefix : '') + property;
},

value: function(value, property) {
value = fix('functions', '(^|\\s|,)', '\\s*\\(', '$1' + self.prefix + '$2(', value);
value = fix('keywords', '(^|\\s)', '(\\s|$)', '$1' + self.prefix + '$2$3', value);

// TODO properties inside values

return value;
},

// Warning: Prefixes no matter what, even if the selector is supported prefix-less
prefixSelector: function(selector) {
return selector.replace(/^:{1,2}/, function($0) { return $0 + self.prefix })
},

// Warning: Prefixes no matter what, even if the property is supported prefix-less
prefixProperty: function(property, camelCase) {
var prefixed = self.prefix + property;

return camelCase? StyleFix.camelCase(prefixed) : prefixed;
}
};

/**************************************
* Properties
**************************************/
(function() {
var prefixes = {},
properties = [],
shorthands = {},
style = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, null),
dummy = document.createElement('div').style;

// Why are we doing this instead of iterating over properties in a .style object? Cause      Webkit won't iterate over those.
var iterate = function(property) {
if(property.charAt(0) === '-') {
  properties.push(property);

  var parts = property.split('-'),
    prefix = parts[1];

  // Count prefix uses
  prefixes[prefix] = ++prefixes[prefix] || 1;

  // This helps determining shorthands
  while(parts.length > 3) {
    parts.pop();

    var shorthand = parts.join('-');

    if(supported(shorthand) && properties.indexOf(shorthand) === -1) {
      properties.push(shorthand);
    }
  }
 }
 },
 supported = function(property) {
 return StyleFix.camelCase(property) in dummy;
 }

 // Some browsers have numerical indices for the properties, some don't
 if(style.length > 0) {
 for(var i=0; i<style.length; i++) {
  iterate(style[i])
 }
 }
else {
for(var property in style) {
  iterate(StyleFix.deCamelCase(property));
 }
}

// Find most frequently used prefix
var highest = {uses:0};
for(var prefix in prefixes) {
var uses = prefixes[prefix];

if(highest.uses < uses) {
  highest = {prefix: prefix, uses: uses};
}
}

self.prefix = '-' + highest.prefix + '-';
self.Prefix = StyleFix.camelCase(self.prefix);

self.properties = [];

// Get properties ONLY supported with a prefix
for(var i=0; i<properties.length; i++) {
var property = properties[i];

if(property.indexOf(self.prefix) === 0) { // we might have multiple prefixes, like Opera
  var unprefixed = property.slice(self.prefix.length);

  if(!supported(unprefixed)) {
    self.properties.push(unprefixed);
  }
}
}

// IE fix
if(self.Prefix == 'Ms'
&& !('transform' in dummy)
&& !('MsTransform' in dummy)
&& ('msTransform' in dummy)) {
self.properties.push('transform', 'transform-origin');
}

self.properties.sort();
})();

/**************************************
* Values
**************************************/
(function() {
// Values that might need prefixing
var functions = {
'linear-gradient': {
property: 'backgroundImage',
params: 'red, teal'
},
'calc': {
property: 'width',
params: '1px + 5%'
},
'element': {
property: 'backgroundImage',
params: '#foo'
},
'cross-fade': {
property: 'backgroundImage',
params: 'url(a.png), url(b.png), 50%'
}
};


functions['repeating-linear-gradient'] =
functions['repeating-radial-gradient'] =
functions['radial-gradient'] =
functions['linear-gradient'];

// Note: The properties assigned are just to *test* support.
// The keywords will be prefixed everywhere.
var keywords = {
'initial': 'color',
'zoom-in': 'cursor',
'zoom-out': 'cursor',
'box': 'display',
'flexbox': 'display',
'inline-flexbox': 'display',
'flex': 'display',
'inline-flex': 'display',
'grid': 'display',
'inline-grid': 'display',
'min-content': 'width'
};

self.functions = [];
self.keywords = [];

var style = document.createElement('div').style;

function supported(value, property) {
style[property] = '';
style[property] = value;

return !!style[property];
}

for (var func in functions) {
var test = functions[func],
property = test.property,
value = func + '(' + test.params + ')';

if (!supported(value, property)
&& supported(self.prefix + value, property)) {
// It's supported, but with a prefix
self.functions.push(func);
}
}

for (var keyword in keywords) {
var property = keywords[keyword];

if (!supported(keyword, property)
&& supported(self.prefix + keyword, property)) {
// It's supported, but with a prefix
self.keywords.push(keyword);
}
}

})();

/**************************************
* Selectors and @-rules
**************************************/
(function() {

var
selectors = {
':read-only': null,
':read-write': null,
':any-link': null,
'::selection': null
},

atrules = {
'keyframes': 'name',
'viewport': null,
'document': 'regexp(".")'
};

self.selectors = [];
self.atrules = [];

var style = root.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));

function supported(selector) {
 style.textContent = selector + '{}';  // Safari 4 has issues with style.innerHTML

return !!style.sheet.cssRules.length;
}

for(var selector in selectors) {
 var test = selector + (selectors[selector]? '(' + selectors[selector] + ')' : '');

 if(!supported(test) && supported(self.prefixSelector(test))) {
 self.selectors.push(selector);
}
}

for(var atrule in atrules) {
var test = atrule + ' ' + (atrules[atrule] || '');

if(!supported('@' + test) && supported('@' + self.prefix + test)) {
self.atrules.push(atrule);
}
}

root.removeChild(style);

})();

// Properties that accept properties as their value
self.valueProperties = [
'transition',
'transition-property'
]

// Add class for current prefix
root.className += ' ' + self.prefix;

StyleFix.register(self.prefixCSS);


})(document.documentElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second portion of code is an anonymous function, which you should be able to place inside the load event callback function like so:

```
(function($) {
$(window).load(function () {
    // retrieved this line of code from http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            src: 'someimage.jpg'
        },
        type: 'image'

      // You may add options here, they're exactly the same as for $.fn.magnificPopup call
      // Note that some settings that rely on click event (like disableOn or midClick) will not work here
    }, 0);
    (function(){

if(!window.addEventListener) {
return;
}

var self = window.StyleFix = {
link: function(link) {
try {
  // Ignore stylesheets with data-noprefix attribute as well as alternate stylesheets
  if(link.rel !== 'stylesheet' || link.hasAttribute('data-noprefix')) {
    return;
  }
 }
 catch(e) {
  return;
 }

 var url = link.href || link.getAttribute('data-href'),
    base = url.replace(/[^\/]+$/, ''),
    base_scheme = (/^[a-z]{3,10}:/.exec(base) || [''])[0],
    base_domain = (/^[a-z]{3,10}:\/\/[^\/]+/.exec(base) || [''])[0],
    base_query = /^([^?]*)\??/.exec(url)[1],
    parent = link.parentNode,
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    process;

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
    process();
  }
  };

process = function() {
    var css = xhr.responseText;

    if(css && link.parentNode && (!xhr.status || xhr.status < 400 || xhr.status > 600)) {
      css = self.fix(css, true, link);

      // Convert relative URLs to absolute, if needed
      if(base) {
        css = css.replace(/url\(\s*?((?:"|')?)(.+?)\1\s*?\)/gi, function($0, quote, url) {
          if(/^([a-z]{3,10}:|#)/i.test(url)) { // Absolute & or hash-relative
            return $0;
          }
          else if(/^\/\//.test(url)) { // Scheme-relative
            // May contain sequences like /../ and /./ but those DO work
            return 'url("' + base_scheme + url + '")';
          }
          else if(/^\//.test(url)) { // Domain-relative
            return 'url("' + base_domain + url + '")';
          }
          else if(/^\?/.test(url)) { // Query-relative
            return 'url("' + base_query + url + '")';
          }
          else {
            // Path-relative
            return 'url("' + base + url + '")';
          }
        });

        // behavior URLs shoudn’t be converted (Issue #19)
        // base should be escaped before added to RegExp (Issue #81)
        var escaped_base = base.replace(/([\\\^\$*+[\]?{}.=!:(|)])/g,"\\$1");
        css = css.replace(RegExp('\\b(behavior:\\s*?url\\(\'?"?)' + escaped_base, 'gi'), '$1');
        }

      var style = document.createElement('style');
      style.textContent = css;
      style.media = link.media;
      style.disabled = link.disabled;
      style.setAttribute('data-href', link.getAttribute('href'));

      parent.insertBefore(style, link);
      parent.removeChild(link);

      style.media = link.media; // Duplicate is intentional. See issue #31
    }
  };

  try {
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send(null);
  } catch (e) {
  // Fallback to XDomainRequest if available
  if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.onerror = xhr.onprogress = function() {};
    xhr.onload = process;
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send(null);
  }
 }

link.setAttribute('data-inprogress', '');
},

styleElement: function(style) {
if (style.hasAttribute('data-noprefix')) {
  return;
}
var disabled = style.disabled;

style.textContent = self.fix(style.textContent, true, style);

style.disabled = disabled;
},

styleAttribute: function(element) {
var css = element.getAttribute('style');

css = self.fix(css, false, element);

element.setAttribute('style', css);
},

process: function() {
// Linked stylesheets
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]:not([data-inprogress])').forEach(StyleFix.link);

// Inline stylesheets
$('style').forEach(StyleFix.styleElement);

// Inline styles
$('[style]').forEach(StyleFix.styleAttribute);
},

register: function(fixer, index) {
(self.fixers = self.fixers || [])
  .splice(index === undefined? self.fixers.length : index, 0, fixer);
},

fix: function(css, raw, element) {
for(var i=0; i<self.fixers.length; i++) {
  css = self.fixers[i](css, raw, element) || css;
}

return css;
},

camelCase: function(str) {
return str.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function($0, $1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); }).replace('-','');
},

deCamelCase: function(str) {
return str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function($0) { return '-' + $0.toLowerCase() });
}
};

/**************************************
* Process styles
**************************************/
(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').forEach(StyleFix.link);
}, 10);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', StyleFix.process, false);
 })();

function $(expr, con) {
return [].slice.call((con || document).querySelectorAll(expr));
}

})();

/**
* PrefixFree
*/
(function(root){

if(!window.StyleFix || !window.getComputedStyle) {
return;
}

// Private helper
function fix(what, before, after, replacement, css) {
what = self[what];

if(what.length) {
var regex = RegExp(before + '(' + what.join('|') + ')' + after, 'gi');

css = css.replace(regex, replacement);
}

return css;
}

var self = window.PrefixFree = {
prefixCSS: function(css, raw, element) {
var prefix = self.prefix;

// Gradient angles hotfix
if(self.functions.indexOf('linear-gradient') > -1) {
  // Gradients are supported with a prefix, convert angles to legacy
  css = css.replace(/(\s|:|,)(repeating-)?linear-gradient\(\s*(-?\d*\.?\d*)deg/ig,     function ($0, delim, repeating, deg) {
    return delim + (repeating || '') + 'linear-gradient(' + (90-deg) + 'deg';
  });
 }

css = fix('functions', '(\\s|:|,)', '\\s*\\(', '$1' + prefix + '$2(', css);
css = fix('keywords', '(\\s|:)', '(\\s|;|\\}|$)', '$1' + prefix + '$2$3', css);
css = fix('properties', '(^|\\{|\\s|;)', '\\s*:', '$1' + prefix + '$2:', css);

// Prefix properties *inside* values (issue #8)
if (self.properties.length) {
  var regex = RegExp('\\b(' + self.properties.join('|') + ')(?!:)', 'gi');

  css = fix('valueProperties', '\\b', ':(.+?);', function($0) {
    return $0.replace(regex, prefix + "$1")
  }, css);
 }

 if(raw) {
  css = fix('selectors', '', '\\b', self.prefixSelector, css);
  css = fix('atrules', '@', '\\b', '@' + prefix + '$1', css);
 }

// Fix double prefixing
css = css.replace(RegExp('-' + prefix, 'g'), '-');

// Prefix wildcard
css = css.replace(/-\*-(?=[a-z]+)/gi, self.prefix);

return css;
},

property: function(property) {
return (self.properties.indexOf(property)? self.prefix : '') + property;
},

value: function(value, property) {
value = fix('functions', '(^|\\s|,)', '\\s*\\(', '$1' + self.prefix + '$2(', value);
value = fix('keywords', '(^|\\s)', '(\\s|$)', '$1' + self.prefix + '$2$3', value);

// TODO properties inside values

return value;
},

// Warning: Prefixes no matter what, even if the selector is supported prefix-less
prefixSelector: function(selector) {
return selector.replace(/^:{1,2}/, function($0) { return $0 + self.prefix })
},

// Warning: Prefixes no matter what, even if the property is supported prefix-less
prefixProperty: function(property, camelCase) {
var prefixed = self.prefix + property;

return camelCase? StyleFix.camelCase(prefixed) : prefixed;
}
};

/**************************************
* Properties
**************************************/
(function() {
var prefixes = {},
properties = [],
shorthands = {},
style = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, null),
dummy = document.createElement('div').style;

// Why are we doing this instead of iterating over properties in a .style object? Cause      Webkit won't iterate over those.
var iterate = function(property) {
if(property.charAt(0) === '-') {
  properties.push(property);

  var parts = property.split('-'),
    prefix = parts[1];

  // Count prefix uses
  prefixes[prefix] = ++prefixes[prefix] || 1;

  // This helps determining shorthands
  while(parts.length > 3) {
    parts.pop();

    var shorthand = parts.join('-');

    if(supported(shorthand) && properties.indexOf(shorthand) === -1) {
      properties.push(shorthand);
    }
  }
 }
 },
 supported = function(property) {
 return StyleFix.camelCase(property) in dummy;
 }

 // Some browsers have numerical indices for the properties, some don't
 if(style.length > 0) {
 for(var i=0; i<style.length; i++) {
  iterate(style[i])
 }
 }
else {
for(var property in style) {
  iterate(StyleFix.deCamelCase(property));
 }
}

// Find most frequently used prefix
var highest = {uses:0};
for(var prefix in prefixes) {
var uses = prefixes[prefix];

if(highest.uses < uses) {
  highest = {prefix: prefix, uses: uses};
}
}

self.prefix = '-' + highest.prefix + '-';
self.Prefix = StyleFix.camelCase(self.prefix);

self.properties = [];

// Get properties ONLY supported with a prefix
for(var i=0; i<properties.length; i++) {
var property = properties[i];

if(property.indexOf(self.prefix) === 0) { // we might have multiple prefixes, like Opera
  var unprefixed = property.slice(self.prefix.length);

  if(!supported(unprefixed)) {
    self.properties.push(unprefixed);
  }
}
}

// IE fix
if(self.Prefix == 'Ms'
&& !('transform' in dummy)
&& !('MsTransform' in dummy)
&& ('msTransform' in dummy)) {
self.properties.push('transform', 'transform-origin');
}

self.properties.sort();
})();

/**************************************
* Values
**************************************/
(function() {
// Values that might need prefixing
var functions = {
'linear-gradient': {
property: 'backgroundImage',
params: 'red, teal'
},
'calc': {
property: 'width',
params: '1px + 5%'
},
'element': {
property: 'backgroundImage',
params: '#foo'
},
'cross-fade': {
property: 'backgroundImage',
params: 'url(a.png), url(b.png), 50%'
}
};


functions['repeating-linear-gradient'] =
functions['repeating-radial-gradient'] =
functions['radial-gradient'] =
functions['linear-gradient'];

// Note: The properties assigned are just to *test* support.
// The keywords will be prefixed everywhere.
var keywords = {
'initial': 'color',
'zoom-in': 'cursor',
'zoom-out': 'cursor',
'box': 'display',
'flexbox': 'display',
'inline-flexbox': 'display',
'flex': 'display',
'inline-flex': 'display',
'grid': 'display',
'inline-grid': 'display',
'min-content': 'width'
};

self.functions = [];
self.keywords = [];

var style = document.createElement('div').style;

function supported(value, property) {
style[property] = '';
style[property] = value;

return !!style[property];
}

for (var func in functions) {
var test = functions[func],
property = test.property,
value = func + '(' + test.params + ')';

if (!supported(value, property)
&& supported(self.prefix + value, property)) {
// It's supported, but with a prefix
self.functions.push(func);
}
}

for (var keyword in keywords) {
var property = keywords[keyword];

if (!supported(keyword, property)
&& supported(self.prefix + keyword, property)) {
// It's supported, but with a prefix
self.keywords.push(keyword);
}
}

})();

/**************************************
* Selectors and @-rules
**************************************/
(function() {

var
selectors = {
':read-only': null,
':read-write': null,
':any-link': null,
'::selection': null
},

atrules = {
'keyframes': 'name',
'viewport': null,
'document': 'regexp(".")'
};

self.selectors = [];
self.atrules = [];

var style = root.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));

function supported(selector) {
 style.textContent = selector + '{}';  // Safari 4 has issues with style.innerHTML

return !!style.sheet.cssRules.length;
}

for(var selector in selectors) {
 var test = selector + (selectors[selector]? '(' + selectors[selector] + ')' : '');

 if(!supported(test) && supported(self.prefixSelector(test))) {
 self.selectors.push(selector);
}
}

for(var atrule in atrules) {
var test = atrule + ' ' + (atrules[atrule] || '');

if(!supported('@' + test) && supported('@' + self.prefix + test)) {
self.atrules.push(atrule);
}
}

root.removeChild(style);

})();

// Properties that accept properties as their value
self.valueProperties = [
'transition',
'transition-property'
]

// Add class for current prefix
root.className += ' ' + self.prefix;

StyleFix.register(self.prefixCSS);


})(document.documentElement);
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks @Trendy. I appreciate you answering. How would I get it to make the original javascript take affect on page load, instead of it trying to open up the image items in the onbeforeload code?